# Custom Google Map v3 Markers for Each Location

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I have a map I am developing. The basic Google RED DROPLET icon shows up as my marker image. How can I get my own custom image to come up? I have individual images for just about all 50 of my markers (will be company's logo).

Can someone help? Here's [the link](http://calwestcultural.com/sgs/example_map.html).

Any help setting custom markers with the code I have presently would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From actual code:

```
var image = './beachflag.png';
[...]
var marker=new google.maps.Marker({
  position: myPosition,
  map: map,
  icon: image
});
```

Your code:

```
var point = new google.maps.LatLng(37.984798,-121.312094);
var marker = createMarker(point,'<div style="width:205px"><center><img src="images/sampleuopsign.jpg" /></center><h2>University of the Pacific</h2>3601 Pacific Avenue<br>Stockton, California 95211<br>209.946.2011<br><small>On the web visit: <a href="http://www.pacific.edu">www.Pacific.edu<\/a></small><\/div>');
var image = 'icons/orange_arrow.png'; // this will be gmarkers[0]
```

What you need to do:

```
var point = new google.maps.LatLng(37.984798,-121.312094);
var image = 'icons/orange_arrow.png'; // this will be gmarkers[0]
var marker = createMarker(point,'<div style="width:205px"><center><img src="images/sampleuopsign.jpg" /></center><h2>University of the Pacific</h2>3601 Pacific Avenue<br>Stockton, California 95211<br>209.946.2011<br><small>On the web visit: <a href="http://www.pacific.edu">www.Pacific.edu<\/a></small><\/div>', image);
```

And change CreateMarker:

```
function createMarker(latlng, html, img) {
```

// Note here the addition of the **img** parameter

```
  var contentString = html;
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: latlng,
    map: map,
    ***icon: img,***
    zIndex: Math.round(latlng.lat()*-100000)<<5
  });
[...]
```

**EDIT**
A quick test with your code and my mods. [image: I set a few markers to a flag]

Comment: where does this go? under the CreateMarker function or below the location code?

Comment: Look at your CreateMarker function, you have similar code. But you'll need two things:
a/ add the `icon: image` line and 
b/ pass a link to the correct image in your calls to CreateMarker (and thus add an `image` parameter in your CreateMarker definition).

Comment: DDA - i just tried it but now all of my markers are gone: www.calwestcultural.com/sgs/example_map.html

Comment: Lol. Genius, I don't think so. I just walked in your shoes some time ago :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can select the image and later associated that image with your lat and long, in this case there is one function that creates the marker.

```
if(location.category=="TEAMNAME"){
    var image='img/blueMarker.png';
}
if(location.category=="TEAMNAME2"){
    var image='img/redMarker.png';
}
function displayLocation(location){
        var content = '<strong><p>Team: ' +location.category + '</strong>';
        var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(location.latitud), parseFloat(location.longitud));
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: latLng,
            map: map,
            draggable: true,
            visible: true,
            title: location.category,
            icon: image
        });
        /*Content window asociated to created markers*/
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function(){
            infowindow.setContent(content);
            infowindow.open(map, marker);
        });
        return marker;
    }
```

Comment: Hmmm... lfergon - i somewhat understand this code. I would like to have 1 standard marker (orange arrow) and 1 discount marker (green arrow) if this is possible. If not, I'd like to specify a marker for each of my locations as they have been handcoded into the HTML itself.

Comment: If you have a category for markers you could choose a image for each category.